# SwiftUI observe published object of published object

Tags: swiftui, combine

When hitting the button, a player is added to the game and I want to observe the changes in the game through the view model. When I hit the button, the counter doesn't change.

It's almost as if I need the game within the `ContentViewModel` to be both `@ObservedObject` and `@Published`.

Can someone help me understand the fundamentals of why this is setup wrong and how I can fix it?

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class Game: ObservableObject {
    @Published var players: [String] = []

    func addPlayer(_ player: String) {
        players.append(player)
    }
}

class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var game: Game {
        didSet {
            subscription = game.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] _ in
                self?.objectWillChange.send()
            }
        }
    }
    var subscription: AnyCancellable?

    init(game: Game) {
        self.game = game
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var viewModel: ContentViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Num players: \(viewModel.game.players.count)")
            .padding()

        Button("Add player") {
            viewModel.game.addPlayer("player")
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want to set the `subscription` in the `init`. This will make sure that every time the `game` object instance changes, you will trigger `ContentViewModel` to change as well.

Your code doesn't work because only the object *instance* is mutating - not the object *reference*. So `game` won't trigger the `didSet`, therefore you will never set `subscription`.

Code:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var game: Game
    var subscription: AnyCancellable?

    init(game: Game) {
        self.game = game

        subscription = game.objectWillChange.sink { [weak self] _ in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
}
```